# Apache restarting : "Graceful restart requested, doing restart"

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, reboot

On a remote host I have an Apache web server running, and I noticed it has been restarted this morning, as the error log shows :

> [Sun Feb 16 07:56:26 2014] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart

I don't think it has been provoked by a human regarding the time of restart, so I am wondering :

1. What is a "graceful restart request", and what triggers it ?
2. Is it really needed or is it a better idea to disable it (if I find the culprit) ?

It may be a log-related issue, as the most recent error log files terminates with that line...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is likely due to log rotation that is scheduled to run regularly. In Debian and derived distributions, you can look at /etc/logrotate.d for the log rotation scripts for Apache.

Log rotation is a good practice, this way the log files won't fill up your hard disks.

Answer (score 5):

Graceful restart requested is normal in Apache -- part of crontab rotation. If you poke around in your /var/log/auth.log (or equivalent on your distribution) you will see the crontabs being run regularly.

Poke around further by looking at your crontabs: with ls -l /etc/cron* or equivalent on your distro you will find a list of all your crontabs run by root automatically. One of them will be  /etc/cron.daily/logrotate which will run the equivalent of

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

which in turn has a line within it:

```
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

which has a list of log rotation scripts, one of them being /etc/logrotate.d/apache which on mine starts off:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    daily
```

You can adjust it to run more or less frequently if you like, but the base settings on my server are good enough.